# Plasmid copy number and Rop protein

Tags: genetics, plasmids, transformation

If i want to transform a bacteria (*E. coli*) with a particular plasmid (in my case pBR322) will the presence of the **Rop** gene affect the production of it ?
Is it desirable to use a plasmid without that gene to increase plasmid copy number ?

I found some informations about the protein cited on these links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rop_protein

http://www.proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Rop_protein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [pBR322](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBR322) is derived from the pMB1 plasmid (which is closely related to the [ColE1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColE1) plasmid, it does indeed contain the coding information for the *rop* gene. It's expression will limit the copy numbers from the plasmid, so if you are looking for high copy numbers, the usage of a plasmid without the rop gene should be preferred.

If it is only for the yield in a plasmid preparation, you could also simply scale up your production and make a midi prep instead of a mini or a maxi instead of a midi. It also depends, what you are planning with the plasmid. For cloning purposes mini preps with pBR322 have always given enough yield for me.